# Dragging files between spaces

Tags: spaces, multi-touch

Prior to 10.7.2 I used to be able to do the following sequence:

1. Drag and hold a file using my thumb on the trackpad (button depressed)
2. Three finger swipe to move to another space
3. Drop the item in the other space

This was a handy one-handed way of moving things between spaces, but with 10.7.2 it no longer seems to work: the trackpad doesn't respond to swipe gestures while the button is depressed.

Is this a bug or was it removed? Hoping someone knows of a hidden preference to bring it back.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by dragging the 'item' to the edge of the screen and waiting a bit for the space to switch. To me this works for folders and text as well as windows.

Answer (score 0):

It should work when you go to Mission Control (three finger swipe up), then grab the window you want to move and let it go on the space you want to move it to. You can also create a new space with only that window in it by dragging it to the right top of your screen and then a new space should pop up.

Comment: I'm asking about dragging items such as files, text, or images, not moving windows between spaces.